# What is mask in Masked Multi Head Attention?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

So I am trying to build a transform , but i am stuck at masking in decoder. So i am using Multi head attention so my input shape of (64,64,128) is converted to (64,8,64,16) for head = 8. For attention i used scaled multiplicative attention. So my attention layer gets input shape (64,8,64,16). I am having trouble calculating mask for the decoder multihead attention. As in scaled multiplicative attention the shape changes after matrix multiplication from (64,8,64,16) to (64,8,64,64) so how should i create a mask for this matrix.
My scaled multiplicative attention layer:

```
class ScaledMultiplicativeAttentionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScaledMultiplicativeAttentionLayer,self).__init__()
    
    def call(self,query,key,value,dim_key,mask=None):
        print(query.shape)
        mul = tf.matmul(query,key,transpose_b=True) / tf.sqrt(tf.cast(dim_key,tf.float32))
        print(mul.shape)
        if mask is not None:
            mul += -1e9 * tf.cast(mask,tf.float32)
        sfm = K.softmax(mul)
        return tf.matmul(sfm,value)
```

My multihead attention :

```
class MultiHeadAttentionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,heads,dim_key,dim_val,dim_model,**kwargs):
        super(MultiHeadAttentionLayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attention = ScaledMultiplicativeAttentionLayer()
        self.heads = heads
        self.dim_key = dim_key
        self.dim_val = dim_val
        self.dim_model = dim_model
        self.Wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim_key)
        self.Wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim_key)
        self.Wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim_val)
        self.Wo = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim_model)
        
    def reshape_tensor(self,x,heads,flag):
        if flag:
            x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(x.shape[0],x.shape[1],heads,-1)) # (batch_size,seq_len,dim_key) -> (batch_size,seq_len,head,-1)
            x = tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1,3]) # (batch_size,seq_len,head,-1) -> (batch_size,head,seq_len,-1) 
        else:
            x = tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1,3]) # (batch_size,head,seq_len,-1) -> (batch_size,seq_len,head,-1)
            x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(x.shape[0],x.shape[1],-1)) # (batch_size,head,seq_len,-1) -> (batch_size,seq_len,dim_model)
        return x
    
    def call(self,query,key,val,return_score=False,mask=None):
        q_reshaped = self.reshape_tensor(self.Wq(query),self.heads,True)
        k_reshaped = self.reshape_tensor(self.Wk(key),self.heads,True)
        v_reshaped = self.reshape_tensor(self.Wv(val),self.heads,True)
        if mask is not None:
            mask = self.reshape_tensor(mask,self.heads,True)
        o_reshaped = self.attention(q_reshaped,k_reshaped,v_reshaped,self.dim_key,mask)
        output = self.reshape_tensor(o_reshaped,self.heads,False)
        if return_score:
            return self.Wo(output),K.sum(output,axis=1)
        return self.Wo(output)
```

For now i am creating mask using this function:

```
def create_mask(shape):
    mask = np.triu(np.ones((shape[-2],shape[-1])),1)
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask,0)
    mask = tf.tile(mask,[shape[0],1,1])
    return mask
```

this create mask of shape same as input shape

I get error shape mismatch error at line

```
 mul += -1e9 * tf.cast(mask,tf.float32)
```

because mul shape and mask shape is different. I cant seem to get the jist of what actual mask should look like? Help me understand mask and how to calculate mask.

Tried reshaping but no use. reproduce error here [Reproduce Error Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ogI-0YybTbT1hfAUdSaUsud9bQ24JhHS?usp=sharing)